# SCALA POI API. Cannot access Field Inherited

Tags: excel, scala, apache-poi

I am writing a bit of code to read an excel file. At this point I am trying to determine the type of a cell.

```
    val wb:HSSFWorkbook= new HSSFWorkbook(fileInput)
    val sheet:HSSFSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    val rows    = sheet.rowIterator()

    while(rows.hasNext()){
     var    row = rows.next()
    val cells = row.cellIterator()
    while(cells.hasNext()){
   val cell = cells.next()
   println(cell.getCellType()== org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)}}
```

It says

```
   value CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC is not a member of object org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell
```

I dont understand why i cannot access this field. Could you please help on that.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala treats static fields a bit different. In scala there are no static fields, so scala builds virtual `object`s for the static fields in java classes. As `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` is not defined on `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell` but on `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell`, you can't access it from there, because inheritance is not taken into account on static members. You can access the field directly:

```
scala> org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC
res1: Int = 0
```

If inheritance was taken into account, this would lead to inconsistencies with how scala `object`s work. In scala a companion object does not inherit anything from the companion of the classes superclass.